# Getting the indexPath of collectionView cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to pass data from a `collectionView` cell to another view controller. I have come this far but I am stuck. Basically, i want to pass the text of the label inside my collectionView cell to the label from another view controller. The code below does not work. I think I need to add some code that tells which cell has been tapped. Btw when i change this line                 `viewController.dataLabelObject = valueToPass` to this                 `viewController.dataLabelObject = "Hello"` i can see it on the other controller

```
var valueToPass: String!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue"
        {
            let viewController = segue.destination as! AnimalsViewController1
            viewController.dataLabelObject = valueToPass
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let currentCell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1
        valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel.text


        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: The way you're trying to solve the problem is fundamentally wrong. Views are not intended to carry data, that's a job for models. That being said you can grab the model which provided the label value in the first place & then pass the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your thinking. Cells do not store data, they present data and gather input from the user.

Instead of trying to extract data from the cell the user tapped, get the index path of the selected cell and look up the data in your array. Also add print statements along the way to figure out what's going on:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    valueToPass = myArray[indexPath.row]
    print("In \(#function), valueToPass = \(valueToPass)")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
}
```

And then pass that data to the destination view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue"
    {
        let viewController = segue.destination as! AnimalsViewController1
        print("In \(#function), valueToPass = \(valueToPass)")
        viewController.dataLabelObject = valueToPass
    }
}
```

Add a print statement in the destination view controller to log the value of dataLabelObject when it loads.

Comment: Ok i did it. When i ran my app, i got this on the console `In prepare(for:sender:), valueToPass = nil
In collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:), valueToPass = Optional("cat")
In prepare(for:sender:), valueToPass = Optional("cat")` valueToPass is nil in the first one but it has a value in the last one. And it does not show up in the 2nd view controller

Comment: It sounds like you are invoking a segue twice. Do you have a segue linked directly to your cells as well as invoking it in "didSelectItemAt"?

Comment: Why the down vote? If you think my answer is lacking somehow, please tell me why?

Comment: Comment out the segue in your `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` method. Does the segue still happen? If so, you've got 2 segues somehow. (Probably one from the storyboard and one from code.) If so, remove the segue from the storyboard and un-comment the one in your `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` you only invoke the segue once, from code.

Comment: I did not downvote. Why would i do that to someone who is trying to help me? Btw you were right i deleted my segue from my cell to viewcontroller and instead of i created a new segue from 1st view controller to 2nd one and it worked. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Learn to use various debugging techniques. Adding print statements is one. The fact that you saw two calls to `prepare(for:sender:)` is how I was able to help you find your problem . You should also learn how to set breakpoints and use the debugger. Invest some time learning it. The payback on your investment of time is HUGE.

Answer (score -1):

You do it complete wrong. First of all you should not pass data from labels, it will be better if you store strings in your controller:

```
var strings: [Strings]!
```

Then, when you selecting cell, pass `indexPath` as `sender`:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: indexPath)
```

In prepare for segue:

```
let indexPath = segue.sender as! IndexPath
let string = strings[indexPath.item]
viewController.dataLabelObject = string
```

Comment: You can do that, but it isn't standard practice. I would not write an answer that implies that this is **THE** way to solve this problem.

Comment: @DuncanC ofc, it was wrong and I wanted to append answer with details.

Comment: I'd suggest saying something like "One option is to use the sender parameter in the call to `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` to pass a parameter into your `prepare(for:sender:)` method. It's unconventional, but it works."